Blazor server bootstrap template doesn't render properly .NET 8
I have an issue after installing the template in my Blazor App.
I have created a WebsiteLayout :
   <div class="page">
        <header class="reveal_header">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row align-items-center">
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <a href="index.html" class="logo_normal"><img src="img/logo.png" width="135" height="45" alt=""></a>
                        <a href="index.html" class="logo_sticky"><img src="img/logo_sticky.png" width="135" height="45" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <nav>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#booking_section" class="btn_1 btn_scrollto">Book Now</a></li>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="hamburger_2 open_close_nav_panel">
                                        <div class="hamburger__box">
                                            <div class="hamburger__inner"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /container -->
        </header><!-- /Header -->
    
        <div class="nav_panel">
            <a href="#0" class="closebt open_close_nav_panel"><i class="bi bi-x"></i></a>
            <div class="logo_panel"><img src="img/logo_sticky.png" width="135" height="45" alt=""></div>
            <div class="sidebar-navigation">
                <nav>
                    <ul class="level-1">
                        <li class="parent">
                            <a href="/">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="parent">
                            <a href="#0">Properties</a>
                            <ul class="level-2">
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="about-us">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="activities">Activities</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact-us">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="panel_footer">
    
                    </div>
                    <!-- /panel_footer -->
                </nav>
            </div>
            <!-- /sidebar-navigation -->
        </div>
        <!-- /nav_panel -->
        <main>
            @Body
        </main>

And update my App.razor file :
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="@NavigationManager.BaseUri" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="css/fluent-base.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/site.css" />
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <!-- Favicons-->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/apple-touch-icon-57x57-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" type="image/x-icon" sizes="72x72" href="img/apple-touch-icon-72x72-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" type="image/x-icon" sizes="114x114" href="img/apple-touch-icon-114x114-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" type="image/x-icon" sizes="144x144" href="img/apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png">

    <!-- GOOGLE WEB FONT-->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Caveat:wght@400;500&family=Montserrat:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- BASE CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/vendors.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- YOUR CUSTOM CSS -->
    <link href="css/custom-front.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <HeadOutlet @rendermode="@InteractiveServer" />
</head>

<body>
    <Routes @rendermode="@InteractiveServer" />
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
    <script src="_content/Radzen.Blazor/Radzen.Blazor.js"></script>
    <script src="js/common_scripts.js"></script>
    <script src="js/common_functions.js"></script>
    <script src="js/datepicker_search.js"></script>
    <script src="js/datepicker_inline.js"></script>
    <script src="phpmailer/validate.js"></script>
</body>

</html>

The issue I have the page doesn't render properly. The menu doesn't work the loader just keeps loading. Unless I wrap the WebsiteLayout with :
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
</html>

Which works however it's is a wrong approach as it duplicates the <html> tag and gives this error:
Error: Found malformed component comment at Blazor:{"type":"server","prerenderId":"83f528a60f284f0fb0100ce2976663d4","key":{"locationHash":"B58C86790BC8BCEE61DF2E802390191A8955BF6986A528B86E5BFE98B3F8B405:8","formattedComponentKey":""},"sequence":1,"descriptor":"CfDJ8EqwM4xZHRRIq6L/2O4kUJZOMKwXjcHhPLB5ZYsfZm1hO19yS3wLiP56yeQtp9fFQprkqXl0r3XSi43JllkNJQSSt\u002BdQxWRtAWcuBiaJ\u002BaJax/qyOTeeNt04Qd0ozUDYlzRTB/puXqozu0zG61xtE2MW5UoLVr98R1KARBtOmikQ7jgg2k01sXWua5g9KocR\u002BU6pgFeD4Fbee2Bpz7Qkzbd1iuxB34ZtPG4jyjOpoFbjKuJ8msiG7aGc4z6e2aZEg/YJYUu0g9WAGzhi1tvF3NO3FuIz6ZVQhqOlKhoZEOmc4CVhi3aREf15OigMR5RH54lzhA20g7POh9xsXuAM/0NvpFjLvdQs5SrcmEQqC1Bk2NOiYNegnWF3xSc8Bgku1ZNfrfr7eNzEDv3wfTmpYbp0IBuDYriYv4vAAPYVsnMLVqAYXFnxIMOo4uPGQ\u002BfU\u002BNGipcJZyLz/5ofJNCxfwZw5iuBU2oagvhEeeghZwmeSqtRx/E0B/5eV0PHS9R9KjlTjmd7HXBJq7hY2UHS/wNv4iTX/sB3/QhlEZJL3rnTu"}
    at Dt (blazor.web.js:1:42764)
    at Rt (blazor.web.js:1:41344)
    at Rt (blazor.web.js:1:41417)
    at Rt (blazor.web.js:1:41417)
    at blazor.web.js:1:40607
    at St (blazor.web.js:1:40659)
    at bi (blazor.web.js:1:171526)
    at blazor.web.js:1:186824
    at Ki (blazor.web.js:1:186888)

The problem is with javascript , there is no errors however when I remove loader element I can see that page is missing the content generated by JS.

There's nothing obvious that I can see [someone else may spot it] in your code to suggest the behaviour you have reported.  You need to start commenting out sections and functionality until you find the culprit, or start with the standard template and add your changes in stages.

I have tested with your code with a new blazor 8 web app server render mode template. With only bootstrap.min.css referenced, the project works correctly. Judging from the behavior the issue could be the conflicts of the css and js references. As other member says , you need to check them separately to find the cause. How is your index file and the loader part?

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
</html>

and subsequent declarations of css should be in _Host.cshtml and not App.Razor
